# How convert this tabular mysql result into a hierarchical data structure in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a small node / express utility which will return an array of objects, each with a date and an array of values:

```
var desired_result = [
  { date: "2015-09-21", values: [
    { value: "val_a", score: 2 },
    { value: "val_b", score: 4 }
  ],
  { date: "2015-09-22", values: [
    { value: "val_a", score: 4 },
    { value: "val_b", score: 8 }
  ]
]
```

This data comes from a mysql query which will have multiple values per date, like:

```
var mysql_results = [
  { date: "2015-09-21", value: "val_a", score: 2 },
  { date: "2015-09-21", value: "val_b", score: 4 },
  { date: "2015-09-22", value: "val_a", score: 4 },
  { date: "2015-09-22", value: "val_b", score: 8 }
]
```

It seems like this should be fairly straightforward with a `.reduce()` call, but I've had a hard time getting it to work.

Comment: What you have is an array objects, not JSON.

Comment: hmm... What made you separate the two different sets of val_a and val_b to the same date, but in two separate objects? were those meant to be two separate dates? if they were separate dates this could be reduced a bit more by mysql using grouping and sum.

Comment: @FelixKling - whoops, oversight.  It get's `res.json()`'d at the end

Comment: Then yeah looping over it would be pretty much the only option. Do you have anything you've written that didn't work?

Comment: @KevinB I overlooked what you meant with your first comment -- there were supposed to be two different dates, each with it's own set of values, I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the `.reduce()` method working; this approach depends on the array being sorted by date (which is done in my sql query).

The solution:

```
var mysql_results = [
  { date: "2015-09-21", value: "val_a", score: 2 },
  { date: "2015-09-21", value: "val_b", score: 4 },
  { date: "2015-09-22", value: "val_a", score: 4 },
  { date: "2015-09-22", value: "val_b", score: 8 }
]

var output = mysql_results
    .map(function (result) {
        // format the records as { date, values: [] }
        return {
            date: result.date,
            values: [{value: result.value, score: result.score}]
        }
    })
    .reduce(function (result, cur) {

        if (!result.length) {
            // no previous records
            result.push(cur);
            return result;
        }

        var prev = result[result.length - 1];
        if (prev.date === cur.date) {

            // prev record has same date - merge values
            prev.values = prev.values.concat(cur.values)
            result[result.length - 1] = prev;
            return result;

        }

        // dates don't match, add new record
        result.push(cur);
        return result;

    }, []);
```

Which produces

```
[
  { date: "2015-09-21", values: [
      { value: "val_a", score: 2 },
      { value: "val_b", score: 4 }
    ]
  },
  {
    date: "2015-09-22", values: [
      { value: "val_a", score: 4 },
      { value: "val_b", score: 8 }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use the [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library:

```
_.chain([
  { date: "2015-09-22", value: "val_a", score: 2 },
  { date: "2015-09-22", value: "val_b", score: 4 },
  { date: "2015-09-22", value: "val_a", score: 4 },
  { date: "2015-09-22", value: "val_b", score: 8 }
]).groupBy(function(el) {
  return el.date;
}).map(function(val, key) {
  return { date: key, values: val };
}).value();
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "date": "2015-09-22",
    "values": [
      {
        "date": "2015-09-22",
        "value": "val_a",
        "score": 2
      },
      {
        "date": "2015-09-22",
        "value": "val_b",
        "score": 4
      },
      {
        "date": "2015-09-22",
        "value": "val_a",
        "score": 4
      },
      {
        "date": "2015-09-22",
        "value": "val_b",
        "score": 8
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: sorry, just noticed that my example data had an error (it should have had two different dates).  I just updated the samples if you'd like to update your answer

Comment: My answer should work no problem with the new sample data.